# c:\python27\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Python27\Scripts\slicer': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, command-line, file-not-found

I am trying to use [slicer](https://pythonhosted.org/cubes/slicer.html) command line tool.

But I get the error

> c:\python27\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Python27\Scripts\slicer': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

But the slicer.exe is there at the specified folder.

How can I fix this?

Update:
When I remove slicer.exe from the specified folder and try 'slicer serve slicer.ini' command I get the message

> 'slicer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

which is reasonable. But it doesn't work even when slicer.exe is there

Comment: The error message clearly says the reason. Have you check if that exists?

Comment: yes, Rao. I have mentioned that in my post.

Comment: Hare you are you calling or using it or invoking it?

Comment: The file path has Python in different cases, i.e., 'python' versus 'Python'. As the python program was originally from Linux/Unix it might be making assumptions about case sensitivity. If you rename the 'python' folder to 'Python' that might help.

Comment: @Rao i'm calling it using the command 'slicer serve slicer.ini'  This tool worked perfectly until I uninstalled and reinstalled cubes. Cubes installation had installed slicer together with it.

Comment: @corriganjc actually the folder is 'Python27'

Answer (score 0):

> Just rename **slicer.exe** in the slicer.